# How to affect the change in the original input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made an input box and i have cloned this input box to a div,let's name them ipbox1 and ipbox2, ipbox2 is the copy of ipbox1 now what i want to do is that when
i enter/change the value in either of them, the dom.value or $("#id").val() should return the updated the value. But now it's only functioning with the ipbox2.
What should i do?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6td1bof/)

```js
$("#ghj").click(function(){
 $("#abc").val("Some text");
 $("#abc").clone(true).appendTo("#pastehere");
})
$("#abc").on('change',function(){
 alert();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "text" id = "abc">This is the first box
<div id = "pastehere">

</div>This is the cloned box
<br><button type = "button" id = "ghj">
Clone
</button>
```

Comment: when you'll do `$(#id).val()`, you'll get the value of first element with that id. Can you clarify me what exactly you need?

Comment: You can check updated fiddle in my answer for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have update you fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gschambial/s6td1bof/7/

```
var initVal = $('#abc').val();

$("#ghj").click(function(){
    $("#abc").val("Some text");
    $("#abc").clone(true).appendTo("#pastehere");
})
$("#abc").on('change',function(){
    alert();
  initVal = $(this).val();
})

$("#get").click(function(){
    alert(initVal);
})
```

Comment: @Christophe Have you checked the fiddle?

Comment: absolutely, I confirm that the markup is invalid (see my answer).

Comment: I agree, two html elements with same id should not be used logically. But, syntactically it can be done and the question pertains to the same scenario. Correct me, if i am wrong.

Comment: This is incorrect syntax, the html specs are clear on this.

Answer (score 1):

You should not append a cloned element with an id as this creates invalid markup (two html elements with the same id).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to read the value of either of them independently, then check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6td1bof/2/)

If not, then I must be offtrack. Please add more details about what you need to achieve :)

HTML

```
<input type = "text" class = "abc">This is the first box
<div id = "pastehere">

</div>This is the cloned box
<br><button type = "button" id = "ghj">
Clone
</button>
```

JS

```
var initialInput = $(".abc");
$("#ghj").click(function(){
    initialInput.val("Some text");
    initialInput.clone(true).appendTo("#pastehere");
})
$(".abc").on('change',function(ev){
    var targetInput = $(ev.target);
    alert('myValueIs:' + targetInput.val())
});
```